# how to create new dataframe out of columns after resampling?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have read a daily stock data csv file. and re-sample each column to weekly data. now im trying to create a new DataFrame to contain those new resampled columns.[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6152.jpg)

when printing im geting only the columns names
[the return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHXxv.jpg)
if anyone could point me the mistake in my code please

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should include your code in the post and not as an image so that others can easily see what you've tried and try to respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you have five dataframes after re-sampling :

```
Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
```

Then you have:

```
df = pd.Dataframe(columns)
```

But you don't actucally include the resampled data into your constructor.
So that's where your problem is.

Try this:

```
df = pd.concat([Open,High,Low,Close,Volume],axis = 1)
```

Comment: tnx a lot for your help